# ManagedObject Class shared by two OS X targets. One app ONLY has Class redefinition error. Fix that does not necessitate renaming my NSManagedObject?

Tags: macos, nsmanagedobject

error: redefinition of 'Category' as different kind of symbol

I have an NSManagedObject Class Problem, where my Class (Category) redefines a Class in Foundation, it seems, but Foundation is in both apps in same project!

My Project has two Targets, both of these Mac OS x apps share a DataModel and the Class in question. One app, the main app, is headed hopefully to the app Store
the other is a utility app to generate an sqlite database from XML for shipment with the main app.

The main app compiles and runs. The utility app throws the error a bit below here.
I am stump as to while this "Redefinition" problem occurs in the utility app only. A renaming of the Class Category, is a fix for this problem, but the fact
that the main app compiles and runs, tells me I could fix it by looking elsewhere. 
I hope this is enough data for someone to tell me where to look.
$(TARGET_NAME) == SqlFromXml_HM == Product Name

The problem utility has:
 0 Target Dependencies
 11 Compile Sources
 0 Link Binary With Libraries
 5 Copy Bundle Resources

---

```
In file included from /Users/mbarron/Cocoa/iHungryMac386/SqliteFromXml_HM/AppDelegateSql.m:13:
/Users/mbarron/Cocoa/iHungryMac386/Classes/Category.h:14:12: error: redefinition of   'Category' as different kind of symbol
@interface Category : NSManagedObject {
           ^

In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/mbarron/Cocoa/iHungryMac386/SqliteFromXml_HM/XmlListReader5.h:12:
In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
In module 'Dispatch' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:15:
In module 'os' imported from   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:48:
In module 'ObjectiveC' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/os/object.h:74:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/objc/runtime.h:50:31: note: previous definition is here
typedef struct objc_category *Category;
                          ^
1 error generated.
```

Info.plist follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.DrummingGrouse.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>$(MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainWindow</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Category.h begins

```
//  Category.h

#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@class Recipe;

@interface Category : NSManagedObject {
  ...
```

}

---

Many thanks for reading this. Mark

Answer (score 0):

Don't call your interface `Category`. That name is used by the ObjC runtime.

Call it something more specific, like `RecipeCategory`.